# Expressions dynamically positioned on multiple lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression

I'm trying to create a plot with four dynamically positioned lines of expressions.  It should look something like the plot below (I've had to do this manually by having each expression on a different line of code and manually setting the x and y coordinates but I want to automate it as I have many plots to do):

[image: Target graph]

All the plots have different scales so it would be good if I could combine the expressions as one object to position in, for example, the top right corner.  The code I'm using is as below:

```
dat <- data.frame("x" = sample(1:100, 800, replace = T),
                  "y" = sample(1:100, 800, replace = T))
                  
mod <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 1, raw =T), dat)

eq <- linEq(mod, 3)
r2 <- bquote(italic("R")^2~"="~.(round(summary(mod)$adj.r.squared, 2)))
f.value <- round(summary(mod)$fstatistic[[1]], 2)
df1 <- summary(mod)$fstatistic[[2]]
df2 <- summary(mod)$fstatistic[[3]]
f.text <- bquote(italic("F")[.(df1)*","~.(df2)]~"="~.(f.value))
p.value <- bquote(italic("p")~.(ifelse(lmp(mod) < 0.001, "<", "="))~.(ifelse(lmp(mod) < 0.001, "0.001", round(lmp(mod),3))))

p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', formula= y ~ x, se = F)+
  xlab("X")+
  ylab("Y")+
  annotate(geom = "text", x = (1*max(dat$x)), y = (1*max(dat$y)),
           label = paste0(eq, r2, f.text, p.value, sep = "\n"),
           parse = T,
           hjust = "inward")+
  theme_classic()
```

But I get this error:

> Error in parse(text = text[[i]]) : :1:18: unexpected symbol
> 1: y = 51.5 + 0.0278x
> ^

I know I can use the `deparse()` function with each singular expression (that's what I did to create the image) but I don't know how to integrate it into my code so that I can position all four lines automatically.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks,

Carolina

Some custom functions are needed to make the above code work.  They are as below:

```
linEq <- function(lmObj, dig) {
  paste0(c("","y = "),
         c("",signif(lmObj$coef[1], dig)),
         c("",ifelse(sign(lmObj$coef)[2]==1," + "," - ")),
         c("",signif(abs(lmObj$coef[2]), dig)), c("", "x"),
         collapse="")
}

lmp <- function (modelobject) {
  if (class(modelobject) != "lm") stop("Not an object of class 'lm' ")
  f <- summary(modelobject)$fstatistic
  p <- pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
  attributes(p) <- NULL
  return(p)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use math notation that often. That's probably why I always struggle with using it and also with the differing ways to add them to a ggplot. What worked the best for me is to set up the plotmath strings using `paste0`. Therefore I have rewritten your `bquote`s using `paste0`. I also made two small changes to your fun `linEq`(replaced `=` by `==`, added a `*` before x).

To put your four labels on the plot I have put them in a vector and also set the y positions as a vector.

However, my approach does not automatically pick the right x and y positions for your labels. And I don't think that there is an easy approach to achieve that and which will work for each and every case. That's why I opted for putting the labels on top of the plot.

Thanks to the comment by @teunbrand: At least for the x-axis position of the labels you could do `x=Inf` to align the labels on the right of the plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

dat <- data.frame(
  "x" = sample(1:100, 800, replace = T),
  "y" = sample(1:100, 800, replace = T)
)

mod <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 1, raw = T), dat)

linEq <- function(lmObj, dig) {
  paste0(c("", "y == "),
    c("", signif(lmObj$coef[1], dig)),
    c("", ifelse(sign(lmObj$coef)[2] == 1, " + ", " - ")),
    c("", signif(abs(lmObj$coef[2]), dig)), c("", "* x"),
    collapse = ""
  )
}

lmp <- function(modelobject) {
  if (class(modelobject) != "lm") stop("Not an object of class 'lm' ")
  f <- summary(modelobject)$fstatistic
  p <- pf(f[1], f[2], f[3], lower.tail = F)
  attributes(p) <- NULL
  return(p)
}


eq <- linEq(mod, 3)
r2 <- paste0("italic(R)^{2} == ", round(summary(mod)$adj.r.squared, 2))
f.value <- round(summary(mod)$fstatistic[[1]], 2)
df1 <- summary(mod)$fstatistic[[2]]
df2 <- summary(mod)$fstatistic[[3]]
f.text <- paste0("italic(F)['", df1, ",", df2, "'] == ", f.value)
p.value <- paste0("italic(p) ", ifelse(lmp(mod) < 0.001, "<", "=="), ifelse(lmp(mod) < 0.001, "0.001", round(lmp(mod), 3)))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = F) +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("Y") +
  annotate(
    geom = "text", x = (1 * max(dat$x)), y = c(2, 1.8, 1.6, 1.4) * max(dat$y),
    label = c(eq, r2, f.text, p.value),
    parse = TRUE,
    hjust = "inward"
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**EDIT** Maybe this fits your needs. Not sure whether this works for all of your plots, but ... The approach below first makes on object from the labels via the `grid` package. Second, making use of the patchwork package you could add them as an inset in the top right corner. One caveat of using `patchwork` is that is does not work with `grid.arrange` (at least I got an error), i.e. you have to glue your plots together using `patchwork` too. As an example I added a second plot by simply scaling x and y by 10:

**Note** The picture does not show the sub-/superscripts. But they show up in the plot window as well as when saving the plot.

```
library(patchwork)

make_grob <- function(labels, y, size = unit(8, "pt")) {
  grob_list <- purrr::map2(labels, y, 
              ~ grid::textGrob(scales::parse_format()(.x), hjust = 1, 
                       x = grid::unit(1, "npc"), y = grid::unit(.y, "npc"), 
                       gp = grid::gpar(fontsize = size))
              
              )
  
  grid::grobTree(grob_list[[1]], grob_list[[2]], grob_list[[3]], grob_list[[4]])
}


gt <- make_grob(list(eq, r2, f.text, p.value), y = seq(.2, .8, .2))
gg1 <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = F) +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("Y") +
  theme_classic() +
  patchwork::inset_element(gt, left = .7, bottom = .7, right = 1, top = 1, align_to = "plot", on_top = TRUE)

gg2 <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = 10 * x, y = 10 * y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, se = F) +
  xlab("X") +
  ylab("Y") +
  theme_classic() +
  patchwork::inset_element(gt, left = .7, bottom = .7, right = 1, top = 1, align_to = "plot", on_top = TRUE)

gg1 + gg2
```

[image]

Comment: For automatically aligning the text to the rightmost edge of the plot, agnostic of the x-scale's limits, you can set `x = Inf`.

Comment: Thanks @teunbrand. I always forget that. (:

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Is there really no way of aligning the y axis labels? I keep having to go back to fix the spacing manually and end up spending hours fiddling with the spacing between lines to make sure it's at least roughly the same between plots.  And because I have to eyeball it, I'm not even confident it's even.  Is there any way of combining the equations into one object before making the plot and then adding it to the plot as an inset maybe?

Comment: Hi Carolina. I just made an edit to show you one approach on how I would tackle the problem. At least as far as I get it ... (;

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for looking into this for me!  This does make it so much easier!  Is there any way of arranging these into a grid of 4 rows and 2 columns and adding in labels (a, b, c etc)?  Sorry to keep asking so much!  I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: Sure is this possible with patchwork too. (: See [here](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html) for controlling the layout and [here](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/annotation.html) for adding annotations like tags.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much!  You've saved me many hours of work! :')

Comment: (: Great. Always glad to help. Was a tricky one, but also an interesting one. And a good opportunity to play around with grid and patchwork. :D

Comment: Hi Stefan, sorry to bother you again...! I'm trying to set the background in the textbox to transparent.  I've tried adding "bg = NA" to the first line of the make_grob() function you wrote then adding "fill = bg" to gpar() but for some reason, it seems to ignore the argument?  Any ideas would be appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Nevermind- I've figured it out!  If you add "+ theme_void()" at the very end when you create the ggplot, the textbox comes out transparent :)